# Changing the output of ElementAPI

Tags: plugin-elementapi

Wondering if it's possible to change the output that I'm getting from ElementAPI. I'm using the API to preload assets, and this is the output I'm getting.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "title": "Hero",
            "url": "assets/hero.jpg"
        },
        {
            "title": "Profile",
            "url": "assets/profile.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is great, and pretty much exactly what I need, but I'm wondering if there is a way to change the output so that, rather than using `"data":` I can use `"manifest":` which is what my preloader needs. Ideally, my code should look like this:

```
{
    manifest: [
        {
            "title": "Hero",
            "url": "assets/hero.jpg"
        },
        {
            "title": "Profile",
            "url": "assets/profile.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here also is my `elementapi.php` file:

```
namespace Craft; 

return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'assets/data/assets.json' => [
            'paginate' => false,
            'elementType' => ElementType::Asset,
            'criteria' => [
                'limit' => null,
            ],
            'transformer' => function(AssetFileModel $asset) {
                return [
                    'id' => $asset->title,
                    'url' => $asset->url,
                ];
            },
       ],
    ]
];
```

If there isn't a way to do this in the plugin, is there a way to get the endpoint file and change it some other way?

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand the question, that `data` key is provided by the plugin. You could modify the source to make all returned elements appear under a `manifest` key, but you will have to do some additional work to allow it to be configurable by each endpoint, individually. Check out Fractal's internals (https://github.com/craftcms/element-api/tree/v1/elementapi/vendor/league/fractal/src/Serializer) for how you might update those keys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

Looks like changing the `'data'` key is a bit more difficult I suspected.  We just released [Element API 1.3.0](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api/releases/tag/1.3.0) that exposes the internal `$resourceKey` necessary to change that value.

In your `elementapi.php` config file, something like this should work:

**UPDATE:** This is the final code that I used, and it works perfectly.

```
return [
    'defaults' => [
        'resourceKey' => 'manifest'
    ],

    'endpoints' => [
        'assets/data/assets.json' => [
            'paginate' => false,
            'elementType' => ElementType::Asset,

            'transformer' => function(AssetFileModel $asset) {
                return [
                    'id' => $asset->title,
                    'src' => $asset->url,
                ];
            },
       ],
    ]
];
```

---

The output you're seeing is defined by your `craft/config/elementapi.php` config file.

You can read about that configuration file and all of the available settings in the Element API documentation at: https://github.com/craftcms/element-api/tree/v1#setup

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty new to ElementAPI though, is there a way you could quickly help break it down for me? I'm picking up a little bit from this page, but not enough to make it work.

Comment: Can you edit the original question to include your `elementapi.php` file?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Done.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Can I have different 'resourceKey' values for a different endpoints?

Comment: Is it possible too remove the root 'data' completely?